# HTML IMG with CSS content invisible without ALT tag

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-content

In Firefox 88, CSS-styled images are invisible when they don't have an alt tag. Is that a bug in the browser or is that incorrect HTML/CSS?

```css
img.wikipedia {
    content:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Wikipedia%27s_W_%28Linux_Libertine_mucked_with%29.svg");
}
```

```html
CSS URL with alt, visible in Firefox
<img class="wikipedia" alt="Wikipedia"> 
<br>
CSS URL without alt, invisible in Firefox
<img class="wikipedia">
```

[image]

Comment: I mean, [an img without a src attribute is invalid HTML to begin with](https://validator.nu/?doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%3Ctitle%3Eimg+without+src%3C%2Ftitle%3E%250A%3Cimg+class%3D%22wikipedia%22%3E&showsource=yes), let alone alt. The question, then, is whether or not this is a bug in the browser's CSS rendering of images without alt text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, content behavior in firefox is different than that of chrome when it comes to `img` tag. content works fine with ::before and ::after pseudo elements which it is intended for.

To note, content with div works fine but use *src* or *background* for the img tag.